# Error: Connection Reset (Firefox) on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I have a problem,

On some computers the following message appears in the browser when I try to access the link from my application:

Connection reset (Firefox);
This page can not be displayed (IE).

Cause of the problem: **Warsaw** (security module of Bank of Brazil, Caixa Economica...)

There's something blocking access to the application for some reason.

Do not use antivirus on my computer.

Resolution: Uninstalled **Warsaw** and Installed **User Agent Override** and set **User agent Linux/Firefox**

If you had any way to get around this block, be sure to comment.

Thanks!

Comment: Are all computers in the same network? this is all server side managed so it's got nothing to do with the browser. The only thing I can think of is if they are on different networks and the DNS hasn't replicated for some of them.

Comment: Yes, all computers are on the same network, but I do not come to think that the problem is in the DNS entirely, because the system works once I ignore the .htaccess and place the index.php at the address.

Comment: Can you show your htaccess file?